# EF6 SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to create a database using EF6 code-first and SQL Server Compact. After I execute `update-database` command I get the following result:

[Screenshot SQL Server Compact](http://s29.postimg.org/ucmqv1vfr/Result.jpg)

There are strange columns `Operator_Id`, `Station_Id`, `Operator_Id1` and `Station_Id1`.

Here is my model:

```
public class OperatorActivity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Synched { get; set; }

    public virtual Station Station { get; set; }
    public Guid StationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
    public Guid OperatorId { get; set; }
}
```

In SQL Server everything is fine

[Screenshot SQL Server](http://s14.postimg.org/yuoe5h7pt/Result.jpg)

Why do I get those columns in SQL Server Compact?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the foreign key field of Operator is OperatorId (and similar for other) so you need to map it. If you map it with data annotation, for each foreign key field you need to map the field name, i.e.

```
[ForeignKey("OperatorId")]
public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
public Guid OperatorId { get; set; }
```